# How to compare columns in two different excel sheets and if match found copy other other column values

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have two excels sheets say input.xlsx and output.xlsx

input.xlsx sheet as below

```
SL_No  map_id   Req_ID  Test_case_ID    Automation_TC_ID    Results  
1       abc     xyz     test case1      NA                  Pass  
2       vgf     xxx     test case2      NA                  fail  
3       fds     xxx     test case3      NA             
4       qew     xxxx    test case4      NA                  Pass  
5       ayz     wrew    test case5      NA    
6       dfd     sdf     test case6      NA                  fail
```

output.xlsx as below

```
ID  URL     Name          Results  
20  0   test case1  
21  0   test case2  
22  0   test case3  
23  0   test case4  
24  0   test case5  
25  0   test case6
```

in input.xlsx we have to take "Test_Case_ID" column and search in Output.xlsx sheet in column "Name" if it matches then we have to copy "Result" column from input.xlsx sheet to "Results" column of output sheet.

Note: if Result column has Pass then it should pass, if it fail then it should copy as fail and if it empty then it should be empty in output xlsx sheet.

can someone please help me to write a code in python.
I'm currently learning python
Thanks in advance!!

i tried this one:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Load in the input
df1 = pd.read_excel('input.xlsx')
# Load in the output
df2 = pd.read_excel('output.xlsx')

df2['Results'] = np.where(df1['Test_Case_ID'] == df2['Name'], df1['Results'])
print df2.head()
```

but getting below error

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1676, in wrapper
> raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled "
> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please share your code?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is an SQL outer join. You can do this easily in pandas like so:

```
import pandas as pd
# Load in the input
df1 = pd.read_excel('input.xlsx')
# Load in the output
df2 = pd.read_excel('output.xlsx')

# Perform the join. The join only requires 'Test_case_ID' and 'Results' from the input.
df1[['Test_case_ID', 'Results']].merge(
    # Since there is already a column called 'Results' in the output.xlsx file, which we don't need, I drop it here
    df2.drop(['Results'], axis=1),
    # We want one entry per line in the output, since the output (df2) is on the right, this is an 'right' join.
    how='right',
    # We are comparing 'Test_case_ID' from the left (df1)
    left_on='Test_case_ID',
    # and 'Name' from the right (df2).
    right_on='Name'
).to_excel('result.xlsx') # And then saving the result in another excel file called 'result.xlsx'
```

See [pandas merge doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for more details on how the merge function works

Comment: @mananonyThanks for code, but what i need is Results column data should be updated in Output.xlsx file itself without affecting any other columns in the excel sheet.

Comment: you could save back to output.xlsx to overwrite the file. You may also need to call 'drop(['Test_case_ID'], axis=1) on the resulting dataframe as the join will add the column 'Test_case_ID' which you don't need. I think only the order of the columns may change by doing this. If that's a big problem then you also need to save the order of the columns before the change and apply the order after the change.